# How to overload the new operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I tried overloading the += but it get's me an error :

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

```
class Sensor{};
class SensorList{
Sensor ** sensors;
};

void main(){
Sensor s1;

SensorList *list = new SensorList();
list += &s1;

}
```

This is the overloading of += operator

```
SensorList* operator+=(Sensor * sens){

        SensorList * lista= new SensorList();


    Sensor ** temp = new Sensor*[this->noElem];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->noElem; i++)
        temp[i] = this->senzori[i];

    delete[] this->senzori;

    this->senzori = new Sensor*[this->noElem + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->noElem; i++)
        this->senzori[i] = temp[i];
    this->senzori[this->noElem] = sens;

    this->noElem += 1;

    lista = this;



        return lista;
}
```

How should I do it? I have to overload the new operator?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with overloading `new`. However, you don't tell us _what_ `operator +=` is supposed to do.

Comment: You are trying to invent `new operator, +=`. Try overloading `+` and `=` properly. Then it should work

Comment: the += must make `lista += &s1` work. Look above in the main method.

Comment: @AlexChihaia Again, that is simply not possible in C++.

Answer (score 1):

However that user defined `operator+=` of yours is actually defined, both operands of

```
list += &s1;
```

are pointers. So this will never call a user defined operator as none of the operands is a `class` or `enum` type. You just cannot overload any operators for two pointers because of language rules.

Instead it tries to add something to a pointer, and that only works for integrals and enums, as the compiler tells you.

In particular, your problem has nothing to do with `operator new`, and you apparently did not even try to overload that.

---

So what to do instead: Stop doing everything through pointers and just overload your operators for the class or references to the class instead. Then you will get something like this:

```
Sensor s1;
SensorList sl;
sl += s1;
```

I recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

If you *really* feel the need to use pointers (you probably shouldn't), use a free function like

```
void add(SensorList*, Sensor*);
```

Comment: I've also tried overloading += outside the class and take the first parameter as a pointer to the class type but i get an error saying that at least one parameter must have the class type. I understand what you are telling me, but it's there any solution? If i right `*list += &s1`?

Comment: @AlexChihaia No. As I wrote in my answer, at least one operand of a user defined operator needs to be of class or enum type. You cannot overload an operator for pointers only in C++.